# Get rid of warnings in List<GenericClass<T>>.toArray()

Tags: java, warnings, generics, unchecked

Another one of those how do I do toArray() with no warnings questions, but it's different from most of the ones posted here.

How do I rewrite the method implementation (without changing the method signature) to make it compile without warning?

The apparent difficulty here is that the Class information for T is not available during runtime. However, the return type is an erased type during runtime too, so there's no really reason that this cannot be done. So, how do I do this if want to enforce compile-time type safety?

Thank you

```
<T> GenericClass<T>[] toGenericArray(List<GenericClass<T>> list) {
    return list.toArray(new GenericClass[0]);
}
```

Comment: A perfect example of why java is stupid =P

Comment: @Falmarri: More accurately, an example of something in Java that is stupid. It does quite a lot right, and a few things wrong. I agree that erasure is stupid but it's unfair to generalise from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  Because Arrays are covariant, it is impossible to have compile time safety for an array that's holding a parameterized type.  (unless you use < ? > which is legal.)

This will always be legal:

```
GenericClass<String>[] array = new GenericClass[1];
Object[] brokenArray = array;
brokenArray[0] = new GenericClass<Integer>();
String value = array[0].getGenericValue(); //kaboom
```

Compiler is unable to protect you from that, so it forces you to acknowledge/suppress that there's a warning.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Java's arrays being covariant. In fact, (see my follow up question). Is there anyway/any case one can create a generic array (directly or indirectly) withtout a warning? There should never be, right? Given the fact, it's always possible to create entirely legal code that produces ClassCastException at the "Wrong" line?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation. This does not change the method signature and allows you to do "unsafe" things without generating a warning. Your code is genuinely safe, so it's OK to suppress the warning. Note that, per @Affe's answer, Bad Things may happen after you return, but you can certainly implement your method correctly.

The Java Collections framework does this kind of stuff internally so it's not just a hack. Well, it *is* a hack, but it's an OK hack. Well, it's not that OK, but it works. Kinda.